# Another epic question locked

Tags: support

The most famous ***[covfefe](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/391945/what-does-covfefe-exactly-mean) question***, with  nearly  half a million views, has also been locked. Though I have no qualms about its being locked, I wonder  why in this case, unlike the “yellow ax” locked question,   voting  activity is not compromised and users can still happily cast their votes on the question and the answers.

Comment: Locks are rare things; they're only given to "epic" questions...

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Is it about how exactly locking works (on this particular question)? Or is it about why this particular question was locked? Or is it a desire to encourage the question to be unlocked?

Comment: There's also another huge difference between this question being locked and the *entire* yellow ax page being locked.... First, the answers are not locked. Secondly, the OP is a mod, he could, therefore, unlock his question any time (I presume)  I wonder if he is aware of that....

Comment: One could ask oneself why the same privilege wasn't granted to the yellow ax question...

Comment: @Mari-LouA - probably because not all questions were created equal :)

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/428046/grammar-of-it-feels-stupid-to-own-cash-in-this-kind-of-environment/428062#428062

Answer (score 4):

The type of lock is different in the two cases, as noted in the lock message. The [yellow ax question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395382/which-word-begins-with-y-and-looks-like-an-axe-in-this-picture) received a "historical significance lock" which does not allow *any* further activity including voting:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: help center.

...while the [covfefe question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/391945/what-does-covfefe-exactly-mean) received a "regular" lock that *in this case* only disables answers and comments-under-the-question while allowing comments under the answers and even allowing users to edit the existing answers, but not the question itself:

> This post has been locked due to the high amount of off-topic comments generated. For extended discussions, please use chat.

I tried voting and found **this lock permits voting on the answers but not on the question**.

It seems that for regular locks the moderators can customise the features that get locked and the features that remain open, depending on the reason for locking:

> We now also have some locking reasons (...)
>
> Content dispute
>
> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info visit meta.
>
> Off-topic comments
>
> This post has been locked due to the high amount of off-topic comments generated. For extended discussions, please use chat.
>
> Both are common reasons for locking a post, and in both cases the locking is there to prevent only a small subset of what locking actually stops.

Source: [Make locking posts more granular](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124749/make-locking-posts-more-granular)

A moderator would be able to supply a more definitive answer to this question.

Comment: It looks like that limitation  of voting activities is unrelated to locking.

Comment: Historical lock freezes the post but a regular lock only disables answers and comments while even allowing users to edit the existing posts. I tried it out @user159691 and found that I can vote on answers but not on the regularly-locked question in "covfefe". I can absolutely not vote on the historically locked yellow ax Q or any of its answers. So the type of locking determines the limitation on voting.